# Convert Rows into Columns in Sql query to column Time

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem to ask:

```
Time     Pass    Fail
-------------------------
08:30    10       2
09:30    12       1
10:30    20       0
11:30    30       40
```

I am trying to convert rows into column and display such information in below

```
08:30    09:30   10:30   11:30
------------------------------
 10        12      20      30
  2         1       0      40
```

Please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to go through the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Additionally read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Stack Overflow is not a turtorial site nor a site that does the work for you, please try something on your own and then post the portions where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    [Time] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Pass INT NOT NULL,
    Fail INT NOT null
    );
INSERT #TestData (Time, Pass, Fail) VALUES 
    ('08:30',10, 2),
    ('09:30',12, 1),
    ('10:30',20, 0),
    ('11:30',30, 40);

SELECT 
    [P/F] = CASE WHEN pf.id = 1 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END,
    [08:30] = MAX(CASE WHEN td.[Time] = '08:30' THEN pf.Value END),
    [09:30] = MAX(CASE WHEN td.[Time] = '09:30' THEN pf.Value END),
    [10:30] = MAX(CASE WHEN td.[Time] = '10:30' THEN pf.Value END),
    [11:30] = MAX(CASE WHEN td.[Time] = '11:30' THEN pf.Value END)
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (1, td.Pass), (2, td.Fail) ) pf (id, Value)
GROUP BY
    pf.id;
```

Results...

```
P/F  08:30       09:30       10:30       11:30
---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Pass 10          12          20          30
Fail 2           1           0           40
```

Comment: Thank for you but that has a error occurred:
Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: TIME(0) incorrect no insert data!
i using data type [datetime]: 1900-01-01 08:30:00.000. and use the same table above!

Comment: The TIME data type has been around since SQL Server 2008... If you're using an older version than that, you really need to make your version known when asking a question... In any case, I've updated my answer and verified that it continues to work w/o further modification.

Comment: Oke. I will look back. thank you for helping me!
Wish you a good day!

Comment: Thank you. I hope you have a great day as well. :)